# Advice on implementing web server security in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, security, oauth, https

I have a relatively successful app in the app store that allows people to view metrics on their iDevice using a JSON file hosted on the their server. The app has a simple settings screen in which you simply type the URL of your JSON file and the app takes care of visualising the data in the file. I use AFNetworking for this.
For example the URL might be: http://www.mylargecompany.com/factorykpi.json

Customers are now coming back to me and asking for the ability to connect to their servers more securely. Problem is there is a myriad of ways you can secure your server.

I need some advice. What kind of standard security features would I need to build into my app. I am confused by OAuth, HTTPS, etc.

I believe OAuth would mean the customers server would have to use it? Can you make a generic OAuth login screen in an app or do you need to know which web server you are connecting to authenticate.

Any advice on even the most basic of security measure would be very welcome!

Regards, 
MonkeyBusiness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Security is really a very broad topic. There is no short answer. In any case, both web service and client app need to implement security mechanisms. I would recommend, you provide both the web service and client app.

You likely need some user login with a password, "server verifies user identity" and "client verifies server identity" using certificates. Then you utilize HTTPS which ensures to transport confident data in a secure way. The web service should be implemented with one of the well known web application frameworks since security is a scary business, and tricky. Implementing everything yourself, might end in a suboptimal insecure application.

You should now read more about the complex topic and come back when you have specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

... most basic would be to use https, which would secure the transaction, but anybody accessing the same link would be able to access the same data. Thus you will need some kind of authentication, starting with a simple secret key passed as POST request, username and password and/or via certificates.

Comment: Thanks Martin. Appreciate the time taken to answer.